# How to retrieve user information from facebook using fqlquery?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have the fql query as shown below.

```
Select uid,profile_url,pic_square from user where name="Ershad"
```

here i am getting a response as below.

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true"
```

But i want all the list.All the details uid,profile_url and pic_square.
Please anyone help me out..

Answer (score 1):

When you get a return result like that, it means that there was no data returned that matched your query.  I can immediately think of two things that would cause this:

- There is no user named "Ershad" that has your application installed.  Note that the name field is a full name search, so you'll need to put the person's entire name in there.
- You are querying with the wrong application API Key

I would suggest you try your query in the [API Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?api).  Select your application, then choose "fql.query" from the Method drop-down, and try your query there.

Comment: No Sir,
I am getting the result for the same name search in facebook.
and in this 

fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true"

If i am not mistaken, a list of resukts are coming.(list="true" in the above result). If it is for other name where i have only one result, i am getting the result with uid,pic,profile_url.
So please help to get the multiresults.

Thanks

Comment: I tried this below query in console,

Select uid,profile_url,pic_square from user where username="subbu"

i am getting results as below.
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?

fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true"

  user

uid>689103803</uid
profile_url>http://www.facebook.com/subbu</profile_url    pic_square http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/v224/1843/106/q689103803_9863.jpg
pic_square

user
fql_query_response